# Free() function in a function make my entire programm crash in c

Tags: c

I get a weird problem when running my code, I had a perfectly running code, in order to improve it I coded a little obj file loader function (which seems to work fine even if, at the moment it is not impacting the end result of the code).

The problem is, in this function I use malloc() to create tables and, due to this, I need to free() the memory at the end of the function, this free(some_pointers) don't work and mess up the whole code. I need to tell you that I'm 100% sure this line is the one causing the problem because if I remove it everything work fine (but the memory is still allocated). To sum up, in a function:

*I allocate memory (double *x = malloc(sizeof(double)*integer);)

*I'm modifying this memory (until here everything work fine)

*I free the memory free(x); (adding this line cause the program to crash)

As asked here's the full code of my function:

```
//function is returning nothing important for the moment
//the goal is to return list of all points
int load(FILE *file)//pointer on file (.obj file)
{
    printf("Loading ...\n");//debugging
    char caractere;

    // count the number of v in the file (each v is a point)
    int nb_points = 0;
    do
    {
        caractere = fgetc(file);
        if (caractere == 35)//if there's a # at the begining it's a comment.
        {
            do
            {
                caractere = fgetc(file);
            }while(caractere != 10);//get the whole line to make sure the v in it are not count as points

        }
        else if(caractere == 118)//if there's a v
        {
            caractere = fgetc(file);
            if(caractere != 110)//if there's not a n after the v (not a point in this case)
            {
                nb_points += 1; // +1 point

            }
        }
    }while(caractere != EOF);

    printf("Count ... ok \n");//debugging

    rewind(file);//go back to the beginning



    //now we read and save the data
    double *all_x = malloc(sizeof(double) * nb_points);//to store x coordinates
    double *all_y = malloc(sizeof(double) * nb_points);// y
    double *all_z = malloc(sizeof(double) * nb_points);// z
    if ((all_x == NULL) || (all_y == NULL) || (all_z == NULL))//check if malloc worked (never failed but you know...)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"Pointeurs");//debugging
    }
    //just variable for me to understand my code better absolutely useless in facts
    double one = 0.0;
    double two = 0.0;
    double three = 0.0;
    char string[100] = "";//to store the content of a line
    int i = 0;//to know where we should be in the memory
    do
    {

        caractere = fgetc(file);
        if (caractere == 35)//if there's a # at the begining it's a comment.
        {
            do
            {
                caractere = fgetc(file);
            }while(caractere != 10);//get the whole line to make sure the v in it are not count as points
        }

        if (caractere == 118)// if v...
        {
            caractere = fgetc(file);
            if (caractere != 110)// and no n after v...
            {
                fprintf(stdout,"Worked"); //debugging
                
                sscanf(string,"%lf %lf %lf",&one,&two,&three);//getting each coordinates from th file (trust me this work)
                //then assigning this to x y and z (here are the "useless" variables
                *(all_x + sizeof(double)*i) = one;
                *(all_y + sizeof(double)*i) = two;
                *(all_z + sizeof(double)*i) = three;
                
                i++;//for lines above

            }
        }



    }while(caractere != EOF);
    //here we should have every points coordinates
    //until here everything work perfectly

    printf("Cleaning memory ... \n");//debugging
    free(all_x);//not working at all
    free(all_z);//same
    free(all_y);//same
    printf("loading complete \n");//debugging
    return 1;//return 1 to check if it completed it's task
}
```

Comment: Post the code itself, as well as the full error message you're getting.

Comment: Something in your program prior to `free` corrupts memory. Nobody can tell you what without more information, such as a [mre].

Comment: When the program crashes upon free() it usually means that you have modified the pointer addresses through bugs, or you have some heap memory corruption. The bug could be anywhere, it is not on the line calling free().

Comment: You need to post all code between `malloc` and `free` to get any help

Comment: Just after `malloc`do: `printf("x = %p\n", (void*)x);` and just before `free` do the same. Check if it prints the same value for `x`

Comment: `free` doesn't cause the bug, but it brings it to light. If it seemed to be running fine without it, that is just because undefined behavior doesn't always crash a program.

Comment: Just did: `printf("x = %p\n", (void*)x);` I got the same values

Comment: Instead of allocating 3 array you might think abou using a struct for 3 values that are related. Also: `fgetc` returns and `int` but you only use a `char` variable. With that variable it is not possible to detect `EOF` return value properly.

Comment: You should not use magic numbers to identify characters. Use `'#'`, `'n'`, `'v'`, etc. instead of numerical values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*(all_x + sizeof(double)*i) = one;
```

This does pointer arithmetic of the type of `all_x` which is `double`. Meaning arithmetic with `8*i` *doubles* not bytes! Avoid writing really strange code and you won't get really strange problems...

Instead do this:

```
all_x[i] = one;
all_y[i] = two;
all_z[i] = three;
```

Comment: Seems to work for the error that i described (im having another problem but it seems like this one is fix) thank you.